# Error with browserify-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, browserify

This was working great using rails 4.2.4 but not Im using 4.2.5 with ruby 2.2.3. Other project works ok but not with this one.

> Error while running `/Users/sylar/Sites/rails/devstart/node_modules/.bin/browserifyinc --transform reactify --extension=".jsx" --list --cachefile=/Users/sylar/Sites/rails/devstart/tmp/cache/browserify-rails/browserifyinc-cache.json -o "/Users/sylar/Sites/rails/devstart/tmp/cache/browserify-rails/output20160318-74935-1daiy59" -`:
>
> /Users/sylar/Sites/rails/devstart/node_modules/module-deps/index.js:269
>                   params.basedir = pkg.__dirname;
>                                       ^
>   TypeError: Cannot read property '__dirname' of undefined
>       at nr (/Users/sylar/Sites/rails/devstart/node_modules/module-deps/index.js:269:37)

Want to use npm in my rails app and with react. I use [react rails](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails) and [browserify-rails](https://github.com/browserify-rails/browserify-rails). [I use this way](http://blog.arkency.com/2015/04/bring-commonjs-to-your-asset-pipeline/) to get my [other working project](http://storklancer.io) to work.

For the life of me, I cant get this error to go. It has been a long time so Im not sure what I did to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add `"reactify": "^1.1.1",` in my package.json file.